# python remove alphanum and numbers elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I remove alphanum and numbers elements in a list? Below code is not removing, what am I doing wrong here? After research in other stackoverflow, they are removing characters but not the elements itself.

```
ls = ['1a', 'b3', '1.45','apples','oranges','mangoes']
cleaned = [x for x in ls if x is not x.isalnum() or x is not x.isdigit()]
cleaned

result = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]', "", ls)
print(result) #expected string or bytes-like object
```

output should be:

```
['apples','oranges','mangoes']
enter code here
```

Comment: If you just want alphabet characters, why not check `str.isalpha`?  `[x for x in ls if x.isalpha()]`?  Do you care about punctuation characters?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ls = ['1a', 'b3', '1.45','apples','oranges','mangoes']

[l for l in ls if l.isalpha()]
```

Output:

```
['apples', 'oranges', 'mangoes']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
ls = ['1a', 'b3', '1.45','apples','oranges','mangoes']
l = []
for i in ls:
    if not bool(re.search(r'\d', i)):
        l.append(i)
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
newList = []
for x in ls:
    if x.isalpha():
        newList.append(x)

print(newList)
```

It works for me. It only adds the element to the new list if they don't contain a number.